# Cant create an Outlook.Application instance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, outlook, win32ole

I have the follow ruby script which works fine while I'm logged in:

```
require 'win32ole'

outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')

ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

ns.Logon("Outlook","password",false,true)

#Here goes the code that sends the e-mail
```

I also have a batch file to be runned by a Scheduled task every day. Everything works fine while I'm logged in. When I log off Windows, Ruby can't run the second line of the code. In other words, can't create a new instance of `'Outlook.Application'`. Is there any way to solve this?

I'm using Windows Server 2003, Ruby 1.9.3 and Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled Tasks run in a context of a Windows service. No Office application (including Outlook) can be used in a service.

Comment: If I'm logged on Windows the script is runned by the Scheduler and the email is sent without problems. The problem occours when I log out. Does the context change when I log out?

Comment: Yes. When you are logged in, there is an interactive Windows session.